# Catalina home directory shows 0Bi storage

Tags: macos, catalina, big-sur

I recently upgraded my MAC to Catalina. After the upgrade the home directory shows 0Bi free space

Is there a way to add storage to the home directory.

I am new to this OS and after doing some research found that apple has changed its file system and the root directory is read only

I am not sure how to create partition or how to increase storage in the home directory.

Any help is appreciated[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste from Terminal as text, not as screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you refer to the line starting with `map auto_home`. This is just the mount point for the automounter, it isn't your home directory.

Your home directory (`/Users/YOURNAME`) is in `/System/Volumes/Data`. You can run

```
df $HOME
```

to just get the line relevant for this directory.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe with respect to the `home` directory did not occur when you upgraded. While the `mount` command for Catalina will show the root `/` as read-only, `/System/Volumes/Data` where `home` resides is mounted read/write.

> See nohillside's [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/417881/catalina-home-directory-shows-0bi-storage/417884#417884) for a explanation of the the `home` directory's use.

Below are various versions of OS X and macOS I have installed either on real or virtual machines. All show the `home` directory as having 0 Bi free space.

Yosemite OS X 10.10.5 shows

[image: yosemite]

High Sierra macOS 10.13.6 (without APFS)

[image: highsierra]

Mojave macOs 10.14.6 shows

[image: mojave]

Catalina macOS 10.15.7 shows

[image: catalina]

Big Sur macOS 11.2.3 shows

[image: bigsur]